# What ffmpeg parameters to use for my situation (explained below)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have multiple video with:

- several audio streams. The order of the stream is the same for all files ( example: English first, Italian next and so on)
- several subtitle streams. The order of the streams is the same for all files

I want:

- matroska container for the output
- to encode the video (preferably using AMD VCE. I have a rx 6800) to 4mbps
- only 1 audio stream on the output
- depending on the source, i may want English or Indian audio stream encoded to stereo 320kbps AAC
- to copy (or hard code/burn-in), the first English subtitle (or the subtitle stream on my choosing)
- if there are multiple audio steams of the chosen language, it would be great/preferable if it will auto select the first one or i can specify which stream to get

EDIT: I'm trying to move away from handbrake as it requires AMD proprietary drivers on Linux (for VCE encoding) which may be hard (or impossible) to install on my chosen distribution.

Comment: What does your research show? Except the audio/subtitle track selection, I’d expect this to be quite trivial.